# obtaining json data from a specific range of cells in a google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to find a way to fetch json data from specific range of cells within a google docs sheet.

My spready looks like this
[image]

And I would like to obtain a JSON object as follows

```
{ 
 "Parts":{"target1": 230000, "target2":200000},
 "Accessories":{"target1": 150000, "target2":100000},
 "Stars":{"target1": 95, "target2":70},
 "Labour":{"target1": 900, "target2":750},
}
```

I've read [this article](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/json-google-spreadsheets/) and tried to adapt it to my needs, but my experiments in doing so have all been horribly broken. I either end up with a ton of unwanted meta-data in with my json, or nothing at all. I suspect the article in question is outdated, being more than 5 years old.

Can anyone suggest a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you observed, Google Sheets API invariably returns JSON loaded with more metadata than actual content. To convert a table in the way you want, you need a script. Here is such a script that can be used as a custom function in sheets: entering `=tableJSON(A2:E4)` would return the string of desired form.

```
function tableJSON(arr) {
  var i, j, obj = {};
  for (j = 1; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
    obj[arr[0][j]] = {};
  }
  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
      obj[arr[0][j]][arr[i][0]] = arr[i][j];
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```